# Question on Completeness of Derived Inner Product Space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $(\mathcal{H},\langle{,}\rangle)$ be a separable, infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. Let $\mathcal{X}''$ denote the space of bounded sequences in $\mathcal{H}$. For a [Banach limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit) $L$, define a bilinear function $\mathcal{X}''\times\mathcal{X}''\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ by

$$\langle{\left\{x_{n}\right\},\left\{y_{n}\right\}}\rangle:=L \langle{x_{n},y_{n}}\rangle$$

Let $\mathcal{X}'$ be the inner product space obtained by modding out by the equivalence relation $\left\{x_{n}\right\}\sim\left\{y_{n}\right\}\Leftrightarrow L\left\|x_{n}-y_{n}\right\|^{2}=0$. Using the separability of $\mathcal{H}$, it is not hard to show that $\mathcal{X}'$ has cardinality of the continuum $\mathfrak{c}$ and $\mathcal{X}'$ contains an orthonormal system $\left\{\psi_{\alpha}\right\}$ of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$; so $\mathcal{X}'$ is inseparable.

In the paper "Two-Sided Ideals and Congruences in the Ring of Bounded Operators in Hilbert Space", the author gives the following argument for the incompleteness of $\mathcal{X}'$: For an orthonormal system $\left\{\psi_{\alpha}\right\}$ with cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, the space $\mathcal{X}$ of all series

$$\sum_{\alpha}a_{\alpha}\psi_{\alpha}\text{ with }\sum_{\alpha}\left|a_{\alpha}\right|^{2}<\infty$$
has cardinality $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ and therefore is not a subset of $\mathcal{X}'$, which has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.

I don't follow this argument. A series $\sum_{\alpha\in A}a_{\alpha}\psi_{\alpha}$ converges only if at most countably many coefficients are nonzero. So wouldn't there be a surjection $A^{\mathbb{N}}\times\ell^{2}(\mathbb{N})\twoheadrightarrow\mathcal{X}$ and therefore

$$\text{card }\mathcal{X}\leq\max\left\{\text{card }A^{\mathbb{N}}, \text{card }\ell^{2}(\mathbb{N})\right\}=\max\left\{2^{\aleph_{0}\times\aleph_{0}},\mathfrak{c}\right\}=\mathfrak{c}$$

Given that the author attributes the aforementioned proof to von Neumann, I feel I must have made a mistake. Would someone please help me out?

Comment: Is there any reference _where_ von Neumann purportedly gave that argument?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Footnote 25 on page 860 of the cited paper.

Comment: No, I mean what does the author of that paper say in which paper von Neumann gave the argument. It might be possible to trace v.N.'s paper to find out what's going on.

Comment: @DanielFischer: The author doesn't cite a specific paper. The footnote says "This simple proof of Theorem 4.1 was suggested by J v. Neumann. The theorem can also be proved directly."

Comment: Seems like a mistake. Everybody makes mistakes sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. For an infinite set $S$, we have

$$\ell^2(S) = \bigcup_{\substack{T\subset S\\\operatorname{card} T = \aleph_0}} \ell^2(T),$$

viewing $\ell^2(T)$ as a subset of $\ell^2(S)$ via the canonical embedding, since a summable family of real (or complex) numbers can only contain countably many nonzero terms. Since $\operatorname{card} \ell^2(T) = \mathfrak{c}$ for all countably infinite $T$, we have

$$\operatorname{card} \ell^2(S) \leqslant \mathfrak{c} \cdot \operatorname{card} \{ T\subset S : \operatorname{card} T = \aleph_0\}.$$

But every countably infinite subset $T$ of $S$ is the image of a map $t\colon \mathbb{N}\to S$, so

$$\operatorname{card} \{ T\subset S : \operatorname{card} T = \aleph_0\} \leqslant \operatorname{card} \bigl(S^\mathbb{N}\bigr) = (\operatorname{card} S)^{\aleph_0}.$$

With $\operatorname{card} S \leqslant \mathfrak{c}$, we thus get

$$\operatorname{card} \ell^2(S) \leqslant \mathfrak{c}\cdot \mathfrak{c}^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak{c}.$$